# do/while and if/else problems

Tags: c#, if-statement, do-while

1. I have to put in an extra "test score" to get an answer.
   (i.e i have to enter six 5' to get 25)
2. I can't get the do/while & if statements to loop if there is more than one number outside the "while" range. I haven't been coding for very long, a couple weeks so try and break down the answers. Thanks for the help!

**Here is my code**

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of tests: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] scores = new int[n];
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the test scores");
int i;

do
{
    i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (i < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value greater than 0");

     }

    if (i > 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value less than 100");

    }
} while (i < 0 || i > 100);


for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

}
int sum = 0;
foreach (int d in scores)
{
    sum += d;
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum of all the scores is {0}",sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `do ... while` will always run at least once.

Comment: Your `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` uses the variable `i` - so it overwrites the value you collected in the `do`/`while` loop.

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't realize my "for" line was doing that, So thats why it made sense to move the for loop up. I thought it was going to collect before the check. Hence me being a noob. Thanks again.

Comment: Inside the `do` if a valid number is given, add it to the score array.

Comment: You also have tests like `i < 0` but the error messages say `"value greater than 0"`. It's ambiguous with regard to `0` itself. The same with the `100` end.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `do` block that does the input validation inside the `for` loop:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of tests: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] scores = new int[n];

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the test scores");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int input = -1;
    do
    {
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (input < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value greater than 0");    
        }    
        else if (input > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value less than 100");    
        }
    } while (input < 0 || input > 100);

    scores[i] = input;
}

int sum = 0;
foreach (int d in scores)
{
    sum += d;
}

Console.WriteLine("The sum of all the scores is {0}", sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is the number of tests, meaning the amount of scores counter `i` should be the same as the amount of tests. Also prefer `Convert.ToInt32` to `int.Parse` since it throws exceptions in case it isn't able to make the conversion.

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of tests: ");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int sum = 0, i = 0, score = 0;
int[] scores = new int[n];
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

do {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the test score #" + (i + 1));
    score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (score < 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value greater or equal to 0");
    }
    else if (score > 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value less or equal to 100");
    }
    else {
        scores[i] = score;
        i++;
    }
} while (i < n);

foreach (int d in scores) {
    sum += d;
}

Console.WriteLine("The sum of all the scores is {0}", sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @Enigmativity Did you? It was late when I wrote that, and only later I realized that OP wanted a infinite loop while the provided score was less than 0 or more than 100, which makes absolutely no sense. So now I moved the counter increment to the "right" place according to what he wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Just for the potential learning opportunity, and and not as a direct answer to your question, here is the way I would do this exercise:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of tests: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the test scores");

int AskForInteger()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int i) && i >= 0 && i <= 100)
        {
            return i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 0 and 100 inclusive");
    }
}

int[] scores =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, n)
        .Select(x => AskForInteger())
        .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("The sum of all the scores is {0}", scores.Sum());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is awesome. I'm not too familiar with Linq so I'm going to save this for a reference once I get to that point considering its a basic application of Linq. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There are two options:

a. Start at 1 rather than 0  --> for (i = 1; i < n; i++)

b. Lower the value of n by 1 -->  for (i = 1; i < n-1; i++)

Good luck

Comment: If I do that it gives me the total of one LESS than I enter. Thanks though.